# Laravel won't pass my domain to the MailGun driver so I can't send mail

Tags: php, email, laravel, mailgun

This may not be a problem with *MailGun* as I was unable to send via *Gmail* aswell.

The error i'm getting as seen below you can see where the domain should be passed but hasn't.

```
POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3//messages.mime
```

the domain should be

```
POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/domin/messages.mime
```

I know I have *Guzzle* installed, I have restated the web server and i know my details are correct. I'v created a test project to do only mail aswell to no avail.

Could it be something todo with my host computer (macbook air) or that fact i'm using the development web server

```
 php artisan serve
```

I'm new to *Laravel* so i'm unsure of anything else I can do.

services.php

```
  'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('sandbox*****.mailgun.org'),
        'secret' => env('key-**************'),
    ],
```

mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
 'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
 'username' => env('postmaster@sandbox***********.mailgun.org'),
  'password' => env('sandboxpassword'),
 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
 'pretend' => env('MAIL_PRETEND', false),
```

A've stopped using the env file so it defaults to the mail.php, but when the attributes are the same details it's the same outcome. And yeah just incase its asked i'm aware you need to restart the server when you've changed the .env and just to be on the safe site i've been doing it when changing the mail.php or services.php

TestController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function ($message) {
            $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

            $message->to('dksnowdon@gmail.com');
        });

        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

the exact error

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 107:
Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3//messages.mime` resulted in a `404 NOT FOUND` response:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested (truncated...)
in RequestException.php line 107
at RequestException::create(object(Request), object(Response)) in Middleware.php line 65
at Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(object(Response)) in Promise.php line 199
at Promise::callHandler('1', object(Response), array(object(Promise), object(Closure), null)) in Promise.php line 152
at Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() in TaskQueue.php line 60
at TaskQueue->run(true) in Promise.php line 240
at Promise->invokeWaitFn() in Promise.php line 217
at Promise->waitIfPending() in Promise.php line 261
at Promise->invokeWaitList() in Promise.php line 219
at Promise->waitIfPending() in Promise.php line 62
at Promise->wait() in Client.php line 129
at Client->request('post', 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3//messages.mime', array('auth' => array('api', null), 'multipart' => array(array('name' => 'to', 'contents' => 'dksnowdon@gmail.com'), array('name' => 'message', 'contents' => 'Message-ID: <9975c6b7d34f1fc93864bf7ff15f702a@localhost> Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 03:08:38 +0000 From: Laravel <us@example.com> To: dksnowdon@gmail.com MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Text to e-mail', 'filename' => 'message.mime')))) in Client.php line 87
at Client->__call('post', array('https://api.mailgun.net/v3//messages.mime', array('auth' => array('api', null), 'multipart' => array(array('name' => 'to', 'contents' => 'dksnowdon@gmail.com'), array('name' => 'message', 'contents' => 'Message-ID: <9975c6b7d34f1fc93864bf7ff15f702a@localhost> Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 03:08:38 +0000 From: Laravel <us@example.com> To: dksnowdon@gmail.com MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Text to e-mail', 'filename' => 'message.mime'))))) in MailgunTransport.php line 79
at Client->post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3//messages.mime', array('auth' => array('api', null), 'multipart' => array(array('name' => 'to', 'contents' => 'dksnowdon@gmail.com'), array('name' => 'message', 'contents' => 'Message-ID: <9975c6b7d34f1fc93864bf7ff15f702a@localhost> Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 03:08:38 +0000 From: Laravel <us@example.com> To: dksnowdon@gmail.com MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Text to e-mail', 'filename' => 'message.mime')))) in MailgunTransport.php line 79
at MailgunTransport->send(object(Swift_Message), array()) in Mailer.php line 85
at Swift_Mailer->send(object(Swift_Message), array()) in Mailer.php line 395
at Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(object(Swift_Message)) in Mailer.php line 181
at Mailer->send(array('raw' => 'Text to e-mail'), array(), object(Closure)) in Mailer.php line 133
at Mailer->raw('Text to e-mail', object(Closure)) in Facade.php line 219
at Facade::__callStatic('raw', array('Text to e-mail', object(Closure))) in TestController.php line 17
at Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', object(Closure)) in TestController.php line 17
at TestController->index()
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: A've added the code I believe to be relevant but theres no errors there. If you would like anything else just say. Thanks for the help

Comment: What code are you using to send your email?

Comment: Can you check by changing the `from` as `'from' => ['address' => 'abc@xxx.com', 'name' => 'xxx']`

Comment: Also I am not sure but domain will be exactly as you expect, the domain name you're sending the mails from. your website name. check this https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-domains.html#domains and https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain ,   http://jamie.sh/tutorials/7/setting-up-mailgun-with-laravel-5

Comment: For me the problem was i've put the whole https://api.mailgun.net/v3/domain.com in the services.php. putting just the domain.com solved it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to leave the services.php config as default:

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],
```

Then in the .env you need to put:

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=yourdomain
MAILGUN_SECRET=yoursecret
```

Comment: You sir are a genius. Thank You. So the services.php file denotes the extra attributes in the env file

Comment: Yeah, i've never come across any where that says the services.php file assigns variables for the .env file. But saying that i'm yet to have a comprehensive read of the documentation.

Comment: @helloworld ask a question and put the link so I can help you

Comment: This looks like a madness to me by laravel developers, I see no reason not to update services.php when their own documentation says to put domain and secret in there, but actually that doesnot work, Dont know why, its weird, but putting domain and secret in .env file as said by kEpEx works like a charm. u sir saved few more days for me after wasting half a day on this issue. thx

Comment: Oops my bad, the documentation says to use 
 'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'your-mailgun-domain',
    'secret' => 'your-mailgun-key',
],
I read it like 
'domain' => env('your-mailgun-domain')
'secret' => env('your-mailgun-key')
in the documentation. So to use services.php, we need to remove env() function wrapper and it works without putting MAILGUN_DOMAIN and MAILGUN_SECRET in .env file. Quite interesting and confusing for starters.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to kEpEx's answer, you can remove the env() part from services.php config

```
 'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => 'sandbox******.mailgun.org',
        'secret' => 'key-****',
    ],
```

Comment: Damn, never noticed that there was no env() in the documentation. It is like reading blindly.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is struggling with this, I found out after a while that my host was blocking all external mail servers.

They only allowed me to use their own mail servers. Might be worth checking if you're really bashing your head against the wall like I did.